# PLSql stored procedure to convert data of column in select statement

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to create a pl/sql procedure in which I want to retrieve the value of column from a table based on another column and I want the output as select query having the field values of the column as the column name.

Suppose I have a table having two columns as

**test1**:

```
column 1 column 2
-----------------
abc      123
abc      234
abc      453
abab     4546
abab     454665
abab     4564566
```

I want the result as `select 123, 234, 453 from abc` when I provide the input variable for `column 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query in procedure to retreive the result:

```
select listagg(column2, ',') within group (order by column1) from test1
where column1 = 'abc';
```